# At what distance can I throw daggers?

Tags: weapons, ranged-attack, adnd-1e, throwing-things

What are the penalties for each range section?  Where are those rules?

Comment: I see the screen is really important as I thought I'll download it if I can find it

Comment: I found a Dm screen and for daggers it says for range S:1 M:2 L:3   does those numbers mean the distance in ''?  like1 would be 1'' wich is 2 squares?  could not find the penalty for the range though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A dagger's Ranges are **Short 1, Medium 2, and Long 3** (*Player's Handbook* (1978) 38). These measurements are in inches. For weapon ranges and some other game elements, 1" is 10 ft. indoors and 10 yards outdoors (see the *PH* on Distance (39)).

In the *Dungeon Master's Guide* (1979) beneath each attack matrix is the note **Missiles: −5 at long  range, −2 at medium range** (74 *et al.*). One can pretty safely assume that this penalty applies on the to-hit roll and that, because it's unlisted, there's no penalty for short range.

Comment: Oh it's even 10 yards outside for throwing weapons! I thought it was only for spellcasting range! and 10 yards is 30 feets (so x3 outdoors). Damn I'll throw those daggers! I'll check if this is correct in the DMG ty

Comment: I added an answer of my own because you didn't answer the main question about how far I could throw them xD but I'm still letting this as the answer, you can add the info whenever you like for it be more complete.

Answer (score 1):

On the DM screen, in the *Hurled Weapons and Missiles section*, for Daggers it shows: Short Range 1", Medium Range 2", Long range 3".

As @[Hey I Can Chan](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/165993/51979) mentioned, 1" is 10ft (2 squares **in my game**) for inside and 10 yards for outside (30 ft which is 6 squares **in my game**) or x3 outside if you prefer. (I'll ask my DM to change it to 1" being 1 square).

No penalty for short range -2 penalty for Medium Range and -5 penalty for Long range

| Hurled Weapons and Missiles | Fire Rate | S | M | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Axe, hand | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Bow, composite, long | 2 | 6 | 12 | 21 |
| Bow, composite, short | 2 | 5 | 10 | 18 |
| Bow, long | 2 | 7 | 14 | 21 |
| Bow, short | 2 | 5 | 10 | 15 |
| Club | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Crossbow, heavy | ½ | 8 | 16 | 24 |
| Crossbow, light | 1 | 6 | 12 | 18 |
| Dagger | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Dart | 3 | 1½ | 3 | 4½ |
| Hammer | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Javelin | 1 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| Sling (bullet) | 1 | 5 | 10 | 20 |
| Sling (stone) | 1 | 4 | 8 | 16 |
| Spear | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

([image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqESz.png))

Comment: This website: http://www.mjyoung.net/dungeon/char/weap033.html also has a lot of nice info.

Comment: (In *AD&D* there's no standard square size. A square's size depends on the individual map. (In fact, squares proper weren't even necessary for play; the game can be managed wholly ungridded like a tabletop miniatures wargame.) Still, the most common square size is 10 ft. rather than 5 ft.)

Comment: Oh really? My Dm plays with 1'' meaning 10ft wich is 2 squares, so there's nothing official?! I didn't know.

Comment: But I'll tell my DM about this, I prefer to be nerfed than to have an advantage and monsters could use it too.

Comment: @Laurel nice of you to do a table manually.